# radio button text in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I am new to bootstrap, jQuery and web development in general.

I want to change the text of radio button using jQuery.

Here is the HTML :

```
<label class="btn btn-primary">
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Option 1
</label>
```

I don't know how to select the inner text (Option 1) and change it.

When i do :

```
$("label + input").html(question.choices[choice]);
```

I get nothing, I found a workaround which is to add another label inside like this :

```
<label class="btn btn-primary">
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option1">
<label class="answer"> Option 1</label>
</label>
```

But I don't like this solution and I think I don't need that extra label.

Comment: Ok thx for your advice, one of the reason that make me note want to add an extra label is that when I do so, the text is not well centered in the button and the button looks strange.

Comment: Sorry - I messed up with my first comment :-) I thought you did not not want to use "any" label elements. Next try: You do not have to wrap your input element into the associated label. Instead define a for - attribute for the label to link to the input element. --> <label for="nameAttributeOfInputElement">. [label tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) (In the end correct label tags make your form more accessible and "stylable")

Comment: [have a look](http://jsfiddle.net/L8arN/)

Comment: Thx, I know about label and Radio button, the problem is that I want my radio button to look like buttons. For this I use Bootstrap like here : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons, and the for attribute does not work in this case, you have to wrap your input in the label.

Comment: ok - i got that wrong then, sry. You already found your answer below I think (`$('label').text()` might also work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like

```
$('#option1').get(0).nextSibling.textContent = 'asdf'
```

or

```
$('#option1').get(0).nextSibling.data = 'asdf'
```

Comment: Exactly what I have been looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the text in a span element like this:

```
<label class="btn btn-primary">
  <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"/> <span>Option 1</span>
</label>
```

Then you can easily reference it like this:

```
$("label span").html('foo');
```

Comment: Thx but I ws trying to avoid adding more HTML tags, I don't know if it's better to add span or label though

Answer (score 0):

try this

HTML

```
<label class="btn btn-primary">
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option1">
<label for="answer"> Option 1</label>
</label>
```

JS

```
$('label[for=answer]').html('your text');
```

Comment: Thx but that is basically the same workaround as the one I propose in my question